# Find the local maximum and minimum values of f using both the first and second derivative tests.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)= x+\sqrt{1-x}$ Find the local maximum and minimum values of $f$ using both the first and second derivative tests. 
I am unfamiliar with the first and second derivative tests, so this is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the local max. and min. differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$ once and then solve where $f'(x) = 0$. This will give an extremal point, say $x_0$. 
The second derivative test involves differentiating $f'(x)$ with respect to $x$. Then to classify whether $x_0$ is a max or min, sub it into $ f''(x)$ 
 If $f''(x_0) \lt 0$, then $x_0$ is a local max. 
If $f''(x_0) \gt 0$, then $x_0$ is a local min.

That should be enough for you to do the question.

Comment: Okay, this is the number line solution right? Where you split up sections where the critical points are? I think I'm recalling how to do this!

Comment: Alright, the extremal point if x=.75, then I just plugged that back into the original function and got y=1.25, and since the function is monotonically increasing, there wouldn't be any minimums, so the only point there is to get is (.75, 1.25). Thank you!

Comment: The function is not monotonically increasing. In fact, it has at $x=1$ a local minimum.